# Why do I feel so cold after workout?

Tags: exercise, cool-down

Recently I have started doing [Insanity](http://www.beachbody.com/product/fitness_programs/insanity.do) exercises. After a workout I obviously get drenched in sweat. After 5 or so minutes of cooling down, I really begin to feel the chills. I have to wear a sweater to compensate for the cold even when I am in a normal room temperature. Is this normal or am I just getting too anxious?

Answer (score 1):

There is an absolute possibility your experiencing dehydration.  I would consider increasing water intake pre-workout significantly.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an answer , just a description of what happens to me during exercise! I run quite a bit, it's my exercise of choice , and I sweat and get quite warm when I do this . Obviously I feel thirsty to some degree and rehydrate. Now! When I do resistance training, or (weightlifting) at the gym, I get perhaps a little warm during the workout with what I would consider a small degree of sweat. That being said, my thirst is twice as much during my weightlifting low sweat workouts AND between my sets as I catch my breath , I notice my skin in some areas mostly lips turning slightly blue! I don't understand much of this at all. It all just seems to contradict itself .

Comment: Welcome to Physical Fitness!  Please make sure you add resources to help explain your point, so the people receiving your answers are helped as much as they can be.